# PHP PDO Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, pdo

I'm getting `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in` when I'm trying to

```
foreach ($query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $row) {
        echo $row->id_users;
        echo $row->username;
        echo $row->password;
        echo $row->email;
    }
```

When I use `print_r($query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))` i'm getting

```
Class Object ( [id_users] => 1 [username] => test [password] => test [email] => test )
```

Comment: You've only fetched one row into an object and then you are trying to loop that object's properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically to iterate througha recordset you would do something along these lines.

```
while( $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ){
        echo $row->id_users;
        echo $row->username;
        echo $row->password;
        echo $row->email;
}
```